# Set-AzureStorageAccount - GeoReplicationEnabled parameter will be deprecated in a future release

Tags: powershell, azure

I get the following warning in powershell for this command:

```
Set-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -GeoReplicationEnabled $false
```

> WARNING: GeoReplicationEnabled parameter will be deprecated in a future release of Azure PowerShell. The functionality will be merged into the Type parameter.

According to Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495306.aspx) there is no information about this warning nor any information about the alternate solution. How can I fix this?